# reload the list of disk partition in Perl script

Tags: perl, windows-7, mount

I have a Perl script that is executed in Cygwin command prompt. It calls a batch file to create and mount a virtual disk (VHD file).
After it is mounted, Perl script tries to access the new disk but fails and signals that the directory is not found.
 my script looks like:

```
(...)   
system ("create_mount_G_disk.bat");
# G:\ mounted 
if (-d "G:") die "G: not found";
(...)
```

I suppose here that Perl caches at script startup the disk list and that is why it failes to access the new directory. Is there a way to reload the cache at runtime ?

I would be glad for any help!
thanks :)

Comment: Create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In cygwin, try `/cygdrive/g` to refer to `G:`. You might also have better luck saying `G:/` instead of just `G:`.

Comment: actually the script works when I restard it again. That means the line 
if (-d "G:/") die ".."
will not signal an error at the second try. That is why I assume Perl caches the disks somewhere ..

Answer (score 0):

There is something else going on in the code you are not showing us. Here is what I get in a Cygwin bash window on my Windows 10 Pro laptop:

```
$ perl -E 'say "yes" if -d "C:"'
$
```

which is to be expected because `C:` is not a directory.

On the other hand,

```
$ perl -E 'say "yes" if -d "C:\\"'
yes
$
```

and

```
$ perl -E 'say "yes" if -d "C:/"'
yes
$
```

Also,

> ```
> if (-d "G:") die "G: not found";
> ```

This is not Perl and your logic is reversed.

Try:

```
unless (-d 'G:/') {
    die 'G: not found';
}
```